# QuantLib in Python, are there any existing methods to handle the options delta on expiration day?

Tags: options, python, quantlib, delta, expiration

Tried [ql.Settings.instance().includeReferenceDateEvents = True] and it works for the calculation of NPV using intrinsic value of the option.

But Delta is nan for an in-the-money option. I understand that greeks mean nothing on the expiration date. But should the delta of an in-the-money option be 100%?

Are there any global settings to handle this delta-behavior on expirations?

Thanks

Comment: If by date you mean *time* (ie date plus time), then you will have Greeks up until expiry, and then at expiry the option ceases to exist, so prices aren't necessarily defined, it will be implementation specific, a feature. How would you define Greeks at expiry?

Comment: for options delta, 100% if in the money and 0% if out of the money. Know of any specific setting for this behavior? thanks